# Middle of the display flex elements

Tags: html, css, flexbox

There are some elements `.element` that are displayed with flex (the red ones). For some reasons the red elements have to be display as `flex`, it could not be changed. I would like to get an effect that some text will be placed and center above the middle of the red elements.

The expected result should be:
[image]

I use another div with `display: flex` and put there a legends but it does not display the legends between the elements (legends are not center between the elements), my result is:
[image]

```css
.legendContainer,
.elementsContainer {
  display: flex;
}

.legendElement,
.element {
  flex: 1;
  height: 20px;
}

.element {
  margin-left: 1px;
  margin-right: 1px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="legendContainer">
  <div class="legendElement"></div>
  <div>..oddXXbboo..</div>
  <div class="legendElement"></div>
  <div>..oddXXbboo..</div>
  <div class="legendElement"></div>
  <div>..oddXXbboo..</div>
  <div class="legendElement"></div>
  <div>..oddXXbboo..</div>
  <div class="legendElement"></div>
</div>
<div class="elementsContainer">
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
</div>
```

What should I change to achieve my goal?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do

Comment: @IsraGab I would like to get an effect that some text will be placed and center above the middle of the red elements.

Comment: @IsraGab let me know if this is clear now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would put the legend elements *into*  the flex items, give them `position: absolute` (and `position: relative` to their parent elements to serve as position anchors) and position them using the settings below, which puts them horizontally-centered above the right end of their parent:

```css
.elementsContainer {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.element {
  flex: 1;
  height: 20px;
  margin-left: 1px;
  margin-right: 1px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
}

.legend {
  position: absolute;
  top: -1.2em;
  right: 0;
  transform: translateX(50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="elementsContainer">
  <div class="element">
    <div class="legend">..oddXXbboo..</div>
  </div>
  <div class="element">
    <div class="legend">..oddXXbboo..</div>
  </div>
  <div class="element">
    <div class="legend">..oddXXbboo..</div>
  </div>
  <div class="element">
    <div class="legend">..oddXXbboo..</div>
  </div>
  <div class="element"></div>
</div>
```

P.S.: If you want the position to be even more exact, change the `right` value of `.legend` to `-1px`, since there are 1px margins left and right on the `.element`s. This will give them a 1px offset in relation to the parents right border.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `<div class="legendElement"></div>` elements - they seem unnecessary.

Add 10 % horizontal padding to the `legendContainer` element - this will align your four elements with the five elements below.

Lastly, `flex: 1; text-align: center` on the child divs.

```css
.legendContainer,
.elementsContainer {
  display: flex;
}

.legendElement,
.element {
  flex: 1;
  height: 20px;
}

.element {
  margin-left: 1px;
  margin-right: 1px;
  background: red;
}

.legendContainer {
  padding: 0 10%;
}

.legendContainer > div {
  text-align: center;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="legendContainer">
  <div>..oddXXbboo..</div>
  <div>..oddXXbboo..</div>
  <div>..oddXXbboo..</div>
  <div>..oddXXbboo..</div>
</div>
<div class="elementsContainer">
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I d-id not post this requirement (sorry for that) but the number of red elements may change so it have to work dynamically. Your solution does not for different number red elements (for example 8).

Answer (score 1):

You should think of your element divs as the white sections in the red background, since that's what you want labeled. Then give your labels a fixed width and position them centered above the elements:

```css
.elements {
  display: flex;
  background: #f00;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  justify-content: space-around;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.element {
  background: #fff;
  width: 5px;
  position:relative;
}

.label {
  position: absolute;
  width: 40px;
  top: -20px;
  white-space: pre;
  left: -20px;
}
```

```html
<div class='elements'>
  <div class='element'>
    <div class='label'>Label 1</div>
  </div>
  <div class='element'>
    <div class='label'>Label 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class='element'>
    <div class='label'>Label 3</div>
  </div>
  <div class='element'>
    <div class='label'>Label 4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```